# One server vs. multiple clients with data communication

Tags: python, sockets, client-server, communication

I have a question on how to implement a server and multiple clients with data communication.

They share the same dataset for each step. That is, a server gets the same step's data for each client. I have no idea how to sync all clients and communicate data file for each step.

Can you give me some hints or a basic idea? An example will be perfect.

Comment: Sounds like a non-trivial application-level protocol you are trying to implement (reading between the lines here; there aren't enough specifics in your post). You might want to check out frameworks that might make the job easier. For starter, check out [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) framework.

Answer (score 2):

Take a loot at these
 [Multi-threaded multi-client server in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544013/multi-threaded-multi-client-server-in-python)
[Client Server programming in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487229/client-server-programming-in-python)
http://ilab.cs.byu.edu/python/select/echoserver.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with details like socket and connection handling and you like high diving, you should look into [**Twisted**](http://twistedmatrix.com/)

Here's a [**SO answer with a simple example of a server using Twisted**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544013/multi-threaded-multi-client-server-in-python/5544557#5544557)